# How to approach data-binding a BindingList of Lists to a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm writing a program that functions as an Excel-style dictionary. Basically, it allows the user to add rows, edit rows, search through them, and so on. I use it for storing and studying vocabulary for foreign languages.
I've gotten a version up and running that I'm quite happy with. It uses a BindingList as a data source for a DataGridView in order to track changes and record them back to the BindingList that I use to store all the vocabulary, and the list itself is made up of a custom class I named "Term", that has properties for "English Word", "Spanish Word", "Examples", ect. What it doesn't do is let the user customize the fields, and that's where my problem comes in. It's pretty much "hard-coded" in that even if I'm studying Spanish or French, the Term class is going to be using the property for "Kanji" from Japanese.

I want to be able to have the user type in what fields they want the dictionary to display and keep track of--basically, they should be able to rename and add/remove columns from the DataGridView. My first thought was to implement this as a List, which stores the names of the fields (and accordingly the number of them, by using the List's length). Then, I would have a Word class that has a List property, and each string in the list represents one of the fields. Then I create a BindingList of this Word class, which leaves me with a BindingList of Lists.

When I try to databind my List list to my DataGridView, the grid comes up empty--it apparently has no idea how I want the data to be displayed and I'm having great difficulty figuring out how to tell it to. I'm not even sure if my approach of having a List of Lists is a good way to implement customizable fields, but it's the best I could think of. In any event, can anyone recommend a way to approach this that lets me add the fields to the table, but also tracks changes and pastes them back to the original source? I need the grid to be used as an editing tool for the user to not only add new elements, but also change existing ones.
It's a personal project, but it's driving me a bit crazy. I was up until 5AM last night trying to figure it out and came up empty-handed. Thanks very much for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I've read your post a couple of times. I'm not sure I understand completly. If I don't, please give some details and I'll try to help.

If I had to do a Excel-like DataGridView, I think I'd use an Array. I would create an array of, say, 256 by 256 and put it as DataSource. Then after the user edits, you read the whole DataGrid and rewrite if it differs from the array you originally had.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in this class:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DGVColumnSelector.aspx

It allows the user to dynamically display which columns are shown in the `DataGridView`